# Extract partition keys from cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How can I extract a list of all the partition keys in a collection? Assume I have the Collection Link of the cosmos DB.

I am trying something like this:

```
foreach (var id in client.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("db12", "coll12"),
    "SELECT DISTINCT c.Partitionkey FROM c", queryOptions))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tRead------------------- {0} from SQL", id);
            }
```

this gives empty result.

Comment: duplicate of [Get all the Partition Keys in Azure Cosmos DB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093202/get-all-the-partition-keys-in-azure-cosmos-db-collection)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas to try to troubleshoot this issue. It's possible that:

- The collection is empty;
- There are no documents that contain **PartitionKey** name;
- That you meant to query the document partition key, which may be different than **/PartitionKey** for example;

**--- Querying and Inspecting Documents ---**

You can query the documents in a collection in the Azure Portal, navigate to the **CosmosDB/SQL Account > Data Explorer > {Database Name} > {Collection Name} > New SQL Query**. Then, run query experiments there and view all (paged) documents as well.

**--- Find the Partition Key ---**

You can double check the collection partition key in the Azure Portal as well, navigate to the **CosmosDB/SQL Account > Data Explorer > {Database Name} > {Collection Name} > Scale & Settings** and check the what is defined on the Partition Key field (e.g. /customerid, /name, etc.).

As an example, considering the **partition key** is defined as **/customerid**, the query will look like:

```
SELECT c.customerid FROM c
```

Or the following query in case **/customerid** is not the partition key and may have duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.customerid FROM c
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify the `Partitionkey` to the field name of your partition key.

For example, my partition key is name, so the query looks like :

```
select distinct c.name from c
```

My query result looks like :

[image]

It could also extract the `""` and `undefined`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I am looking for a generalized code to extract the list of partition keys of documents. For eg, here I am using Family Database and I have chosen 'LastName' as the partition key. I know if I directly do 
[ SELECT DISTINCT c.LastName FROM c ] it will give me the result I want. But there should be a  way to extract the same result without explicitly specifying the Partition Key.

Comment: if u don't know which property stands for PartitionKey, u can find it out using `ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(collection)` from `Resource.PartitionKey` property. And than u can do distinct query by concrete property (partition key)