# Is it possible to fetch Partition Key of a collection in CosmosDB using their SDK?

Tags: azure, http, azure-cosmosdb, azure-sdk-.net, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using RESTfull HTTP request to fetch the Partition Key of a collection. I am doing:

```
        response = client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(baseUri, resourceLink)).Result;
        var data3 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
        if (data3["partitionKey"] != null)
        {
            string partitionKey = data3["partitionKey"]["paths"][0].ToString();
            string PartitionKey = partitionKey.Substring(1);
            return PartitionKey;
        }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Do their SDK's have a direct way to fetch the Partition Key?

**UPDATE**

My response on fetching partition key range is:

`item={
  "_rid": "lIB0ALrgyAACAAAAAAAAUA==",
  "id": "0",
  "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-0318-18b49de501d4\"",
  "minInclusive": "",
  "maxExclusive": "FF",
  "ridPrefix": 0,
  "_self": "dbs/lIB0AA==/colls/lIB0ALrgyAA=/pkranges/lIB0ALrgyAACAAAAAAAAUA==/",
  "throughputFraction": 1.0,
  "status": "online",
  "parents": [],
  "_ts": 1528895512
}`

How does this take me close to finding out what the partition key is?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with standard cosmos .Net client ?

```
            var col = await CosmosClient.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
            dataBaseName,
            collectionName));

            var pathes = col.Resource.PartitionKey.Paths;
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET SDK gives you the ability to query partition ranges using ReadPartitionKeyRangeFeedAsync.

[Get all the Partition Keys in Azure Cosmos DB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093202/get-all-the-partition-keys-in-azure-cosmos-db-collection)

So yes, the .NET SDK gives you a means for finding partition keys.

Comment: Yeah I understand how I can get the partition key range. But how do I get the name of the partition key from there?
I get this response: 

`item={
  "_rid": "lIB0ALrgyAACAAAAAAAAUA==",
  "id": "0",
  "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-0318-18b49de501d4\"",
  "minInclusive": "",
  "maxExclusive": "FF",
  "ridPrefix": 0,
  "_self": "dbs/lIB0AA==/colls/lIB0ALrgyAA=/pkranges/lIB0ALrgyAACAAAAAAAAUA==/",
  "throughputFraction": 1.0,
  "status": "online",
  "parents": [],
  "_ts": 1528895512
}` How does this take me close to finding the Partition Key of the specified collection?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not possible, and they won't change this

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/38737903-method-to-get-all-partitionkeys-of-a-collection-c